# Can the warlock's One with Shadows eldritch invocation be used at will in a Ravenloft game?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, warlock, ravenloft, eldritch-invocations

Can the warlock's One with Shadows [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations) be used at will in a Ravenloft game?

> #### One with Shadows
>
> ***Prerequisite:** 5th level*
>
> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible until you move or take an action or a reaction.

The GM describes that the lands of Barovia barely see any sunlight. **Does that qualify as dim light where One With Shadows can be very used at will?**

If it can be, is this ability overpowered compared to other invocations in a Ravenloft game?

Comment: Semi-related: [Does the invisibility from 'One with Shadows' Eldritch Invocation end if the area of darkness you're in becomes light?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70753/does-the-invisibility-from-one-with-shadows-eldritch-invocation-end-if-the-are)

Comment: I have removed the secondary more general question about hiding in shadows triggering this invocation. This is best asked in another question.

Answer (score 10):

### You still can't use the Invocation under certain circumstances

From the chapter 2, Lands of Barovia (CoS spoilers, **emphasis mine**):

> Even during the day, the sky is dimmed by fog or storm clouds, or the light is strangely muted. **Barovian daylight is bright light**, yet it isn't considered sunlight for the purpose of effects and vulnerabilities, such as a vampire's, tied to sunlight.

Other than the information above, all the normal rules for illumination apply in Barovia as usual. The rules for [vision and light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) specify 3 distinct categories of illumination:

> The presence or absence of light in an environment creates three categories of illumination: **bright light, dim light, and darkness**.

Since the invocation requires "an area of dim light or darkness" this is not always the case in Barovia.

Comment: This is where the part of ducking behind a shadow big enough to cover the PC enough to trigger the Invocation?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver That is completely independent of being in Barovia, though, isn't it? This answers the question on whether the Invocation can be used "always" which is no.

Comment: You may also want to reference the general rules on [vision and light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight), specifically as they relate to dim light and darkness.

Comment: @V2Blast: Thanks that should help as it might shed some light in whether hiding in a large enough shadow counts as dim light.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver To be honest I think the question "Is a shadow enough to count as dim light to use One with Shadows?" is a question that has nothing to do with Barovia and I think you could ask it separately if the rules on vision and light linked by V2Blast are not enough. You'd probably get a more thorough explanation than what I can provide on that particular point.